# Turn the Branchs to be folders of master?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo in Github.

```
repo:
 - master
 - a
 - b
```

I want to turn the branches(a, b) to be folders behind the `master` like `master/a`, `master/b` and delete `a` and `b`

Comment: So you want your branches to have a folder-like structure, or do you want to move the contents of your branches to a folder?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: @punitvara:  No, that's not what's intended at all...

Comment: @Makoto I want the one branch to be a folder of the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the impression that you're misunderstanding how branches work.  [Check out this interactive tutorial](http://www.wei-wang.com/ExplainGitWithD3/#) which shows you what happens realistically when you branch off of master.

Now, for some verbal explanation:

- The likely case is that each of your branches is already a child off of a commit from master.
- There is no need to subclass your branch names underneath master, nor can you - you'd get an error that says something like, `fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master/foo': 'refs/heads/master' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/master/foo'`.
- You *can*, however, name your branches similar to folders, so you could have `hotfixes/release/18`, for example.
- You should stick to the basic convention of naming your branches after what they represent.  If you need to figure out where it came from, you can use `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` to figure out where it came from originally.